# Parsing KML file using pyKML

Tags: python, dataframe, parsing, kml, pykml

I'm learning how to parse KML files in Python using the pyKML module. The specific file I'm using can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata?hl=fr) and I've also added it at the bottom of this post. I have saved the file on my computer and name it `test.kml`.

After some research, I managed to extract a specific portion of the `test.kml` file and save the result to a DataFrame. Here's my code:

```
from pykml import parser
import pandas as pd

filename = 'test.kml'
with open(filename) as fobj:
    folder = parser.parse(fobj).getroot().Document

plnm = []

for pm in folder.Placemark:
    plnm1 = pm.name
    plnm.append(plnm1.text)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['name'] = plnm

print(df)
          name
0   Club house
1  By the lake
```

I would like to add a new column to my DataFrame corresponding to the value of the `"holeNumber"`. I have tried to add the following lines in my `for` loop but without success.

```
for pm in folder.Placemark:
    plnm1 = pm.name
    val1 = pm.ExtendedData.holeNumber.value
    plnm.append(plnm1.text)
    val.append(val1.text)
```

I'm not sure how to access the value from that specific node. The resulting DataFrame I'm looking for is the following:

```
| name        | holeNumber |
|-------------|------------|
| Club house  | 1          |
| By the lake | 5          |
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
  <name>My Golf Course Example</name>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Club house</name>
    <ExtendedData>
      <Data name="holeNumber">
        <value>1</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="holeYardage">
        <value>234</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="holePar">
        <value>4</value>
      </Data>
    </ExtendedData>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-111.956,33.5043</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>By the lake</name>
    <ExtendedData>
      <Data name="holeNumber">
        <value>5</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="holeYardage">
        <value>523</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="holePar">
        <value>5</value>
      </Data>
    </ExtendedData>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-111.95,33.5024</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick way to parse the KML.

```
plnm = []
holeNumber = []
for pm in folder.Placemark:
    plnm1 = pm.name
    val1 = pm.ExtendedData.Data[0].value
    plnm.append(plnm1.text)
    holeNumber.append(val1.text)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['name'] = plnm
df['holeNumber'] = holeNumber

print(df)
```

Or

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('name', 'holeNumber'))
for pm in folder.Placemark:
    name = pm.name.text
    value = pm.ExtendedData.Data[0].value.text
    df = df.append({ 'name' : name, 'holeNumber' : value }, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
          name holeNumber
0   Club house          1
1  By the lake          5
```